# Замена PageRequest в Spring 5 (Deprecated)

Tags: java, spring

При использовании `PageRequest` в `Spring 5` его перечёркивает и пишет, что он `Deprecated`. Подскажите, чем теперь пользоваться в `Spring` вместо этого класса?

Comment: Там прямо в комментарии написано, что вместо конструктора надо использовать статичный метод `PageRequest.of()`

Comment: Спасибо. А где там прямо в комментарии написано? В доках спринга и класса не вижу. Выделите свой коммент в отдельный ответ, чтобы я мог его принять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написано в документационных комментариях, вместо обычного конструктора нужно использовать статичную обертку `PageRequest.of()`:

> Constructor and Description
>
> PageRequest(int page, int size)
>   Deprecated. use of(int, int) instead.
>
> PageRequest(int page, int size,
>   Sort.Direction direction, String... properties)
>   Deprecated. use #of(int, int, Direction, String...) instead.
>
> PageRequest(int page, int size, Sort sort)
>   Deprecated.  since 2.0, use of(int, int, Sort)
>   instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html