# Чем заменить PageRequest ? {deprecated}

Tags: java, spring

[Spring официальная инфа](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)

[Ссылка на не решенный вопрос Ru.SOF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769284/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-pagerequest-%D0%B2-spring-5-deprecated)

Через PageRequest.of(int, int);
Тоже не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам `PageRequest` не устарел, устарели его конструкторы. Заменить их можно соответствующими фабричными методами `of`, того же `PageRequest`.

Comment: Например есть метод:
public List<Detail> findAll(Integer page) {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, 10);
        Page<Detail> pageList = detailRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return  pageList.getContent();
    }

Если написать:
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest.of(page, 10);
Подсветит красным или я не правильно понимаю как заменить?

Comment: Без `new`, просто `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 10)`

Comment: Точно, это же метод. ))) Спасибо.

Comment: А вообще использовать эту утилиту не нужно, вбивайте в аргументы функции контроллера запись вида @DefaultPageable Pageable pageable и будет вам счастье без обработки линковки